# Finding folder by specific word in title

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, findstr

I'm trying to, with use of a batch file open a folder which has a specific word in it (in this case "Folder") and storing it into a variable. Is this done using Findstr?

```
"C:\Users\G\Documents\File Folder"
```

Comment: Will the "Folder" part always be at the end of the name?

Comment: What happens when it finds multiple folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%a in ("*Folder") do set "FolderVar=%%a"
echo %FolderVar%
copy "C:/sourcefolder/somefile.txt" "%FolderVar%/somefile.txt"
start "" "%FolderVar%"
pause
```

Note that this looks for Folder at the end of the pathname, if it should look anywhere in the name you should replace `*Folder*` with `*Folder`, but that will cause all subfolders of the "Folder" folder to be found. The variable only saves the last found occurence, if you want to do something with every occurence you should put your logic inside the loop.

The start command opens the folder in explorer. You can use the `copy` command to copy files to the folder.

Comment: So how do I open and copy files to the folder?

Comment: Do you want to copy the files to the folder using batch or manually?

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to copy files to and open the folder. If you feel like my answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the check to the left of it, or comment with any problems you still have so I can help you with them.